# Powershell error with multiline command call - Missing expression after unary operator '-'

Tags: powershell

I've called the following command, using backticks to place the parameters on separate lines

```
Create-WebSite -Name $targetWebSite ` 
    -Location $targetWebSiteDir
```

However this is returning the following error:

```
- <<<< Location $targetWebSiteDir ` [<<==>>] Exception: Missing expression after unary operator '-'.
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This turned out to be caused by a space being present after the backtick (`) character.

So,

```
Create-WebSite -Name $targetWebSite ` <- SPACE HERE
    -Location $targetWebSiteDir
```

became

```
Create-WebSite -Name $targetWebSite `<- NO SPACE
    -Location $targetWebSiteDir
```

Once I removed the space everything ran correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I have resolved this issue by using \ at end of line or we can remove spaces.
For you it could

```
Create-WebSite -Name $targetWebSite `\ 
    -Location $targetWebSiteDir
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.